# Does this popup view violate HIGS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

Will using a popup view to present a comment submission form violate the HIGS?  I may have one popup with selections that goes to the final popup.   Two popups back to back.  This is more similar to a modal type of view than an alert or action sheet as described by the HIGS: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ModalViews/ModalViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH11-SW1 under the section 'Using Modal Views'.  Basically the type of view I'm shooting for is a combination of an alert with a custom view.  It's sort of a mini view since it will be centered in the middle of the screen but not take up all of the viewing area.  I'm fairly sure that is a violation however, but I'm looking for a few opinions on it.

I believe what needs to happen is use a modal view, which will cover the entire view.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really say if having two of popups like this back-to-back would be a HIG violation, but Apple doesn't seem to have any problems with alert views with embedded controls. I've successfully used an alert view with an embedded UITextField and rating stars/slider.

It probably depends on how much you want to diverge from the looks of a standard alert view.